# AS400 FTP to windows server

Tags: ftp, ibm-midrange

I want to write a CLLE Program to transfer Files from the IFS to a Webserver.

The Webserver is registered in the Hosttable from the Iseries.
(`commandline: CFGTCP -> Option 10 -> Scroll to the Webserver IP`)

Current CLLE Program: (only the ftp-access)

```
PGM  
OVRDBF     FILE(INPUT) TOFILE(CMDDTAR7_2/US9FIP) OVRSCOPE(*JOB)  
OVRDBF     FILE(OUTPUT) TOFILE(CMDDTAR7_2/US9FOP) + 
             OVRSCOPE(*JOB)  
FTP        RMTSYS('10.1.2.99') 
ENDPGM
```

After i call my Program i get some results in a PF-File.
The Results are in German but i translated shortly for you.

`The Connection is unavalable to 10.1.2.99 on Port 21. Try it again later.
[...]`

My Question at the end.
Do you have some solutions for me to transfer xml files to my Webserver from the iseries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're writing about a web server and you want to transfer files by ftp. Perhaps you're mixing up protocols here. I'll concentrate to resolve your apparent ftp connection problem.

Seems that the destination host 10.1.2.99 doesn't accept connections on Port 21.

Please make sure, there's no firewall or other stuff blocking your request to the destination host. Moreover, on the host 10.1.2.99 try `telnet 10.1.2.99 ftp` or `ftp 10.1.2.99` in a command window, depending on OS and installed components.

Before automating, just test manually if you can successfully connect and log in via standard command line: `ftp 10.1.2.99`.

Transferring data by FTP is just fine in a local LAN. Beware that any data including username and password will be transferred in clear text and thus can be possibly read by others as the intended hosts.

Comment: once the OP gets his connection issues straightened out, consider using Scott Klements [FTP API](http://www.scottklement.com/ftpapi/) ... much better control and error handling compared to using OVRDBF and the built in FTP client.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The manuel test dont work. I can't transfer files with the FTP protocol in the local LAN. Maybe FTP is the false way to transfer the files from the IFS. Actual i test it with some windows Funktion like robocopy. This works fine in the local LAN but after the test phase i want to go online. The Webserver get no privileges in the local LAN. Yes there are some Usernames and passwords included.

Answer (score 0):

Following up to your comment: Actually there are many possibilities to copy files. If you're running a recent version of IBM i, I'd opt for using scp. It's encrypted and thus safe for running outside of local LANs. Great to automate by utilizing Key-Authentication instead of passwords. And many web hosting companies offer scp/sftp access.

Comment: We can close my question. I found a simple save way to transfer my files. I use a man in the middle system. Transfer the files cross this Server. IFS (AS400) -> SERVER -> Webserver. There are only a one way communication.

Comment: @Dominik: You'll have to "close" your question by tagging one answer as correct.